# Unity Input.GetKeyDown doesn't work with several keys

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard, detection

For my game, I need to detect the pressing of the comma, period and minus key. None of them work, despite detection of other keys working. I suspect it has something to do with the fact I have a German keyboard, but got no idea how to fix it. Help would be appreciated!

```
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Comma)
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Minus)
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Period)
```

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

You may be calling them incorrectly. Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            print("space key was pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect it has something to do with the fact I have a German
> keyboard

To simply debug this, you could try following to check key presses

```
private void Update() {

    foreach(KeyCode vKey in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode))){

        if(Input.GetKey(vKey)){
            Debug.Log($"Pressed {vKey.ToString()}");         
        }
    }
}
```

Above code will debug the currently pressed key, so if you press comma and it outputs comma then you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a keyboard with a German layout, but the following works well (I think this is as same as what you did, though):

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Comma)) {
        Debug.Log("Comma was pressed");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Minus))
    {
        Debug.Log("Minus was pressed");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Period))
    {
        Debug.Log("Period was pressed");
    }
}
```

I have also been using the same German keyboard with different language layouts (so, the positions of the comma and the others are changed), but it works as well. I think it's not because of the keyboard layout.

There is another way to write for input detection like below:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(",")) {
        Debug.Log("Comma was pressed");
}
```

If you use OnGUI() function, this is also available...

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    if (Event.current.Equals(Event.KeyboardEvent(",")))
    {
        Debug.Log("Comma was pressed");
    }
}
```